# troubles with rails crypt_keeper gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, rubygems

i'm having some troubles with the crypt keeper gem.  i'm using version 2.0.1.

i've managed to set all the elements such as the salt and the key, and i've also been successful at encrypting and decrypting an existing table.  i've done this using both :active_support as well as :mysql_aes_new (using mariadb 10.7).

i have ultimately decided that i will have to use :mysql_aes_new because it has been indicated that this allows for data to be 'indexed and searched quickly'.

yet, when i employ the sample scope using a .where directive, i am consistently getting an empty results set.  i don't really require the subsequent plaintext search that is indicated in the example.  i've tried performing this on a field within the table that is encrypted as well as a field that is not; regardless, the search yields a null set.

am i possibly missing something?  specifically, i am trying to set a scope were i need to find all records where a particular field is not null, e.g:

```
record_set = Modelname.where('fieldname != ?', nil).order(id: desc)
```

beyond that, i am trying to use update_column in order to set a value for some rows, and an error is being thrown along the lines of

```
Column :<FIELD_NAME> must be of type 'text' or 'binary' to be used for encryption
```

The field indicated in the error is not the first field in the table, but it IS the first field that is encrypted.  yet, i'm not trying to update that field, only the one i'm interested in.

very odd.  a bit cryptic (pun intended).

Comment: Well "is not null" is not `!= NULL` it is literally `IS NOT NULL`. NULL is not comparable and thus comparable method not do work. NULL is not equal to anything not even NULL

Comment: Slowly figuring this out. Managed to get some results by reformulating the query to find '' rather than null. Rolled back database and did migrations incrementally. We'll see how it goes.